# JqGrid: How to get all column values from onCellSelect event?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am developing an ASP.NET mvc project which uses JqGrid for generating report. For report generation i am generating 2 different reports . Second report will be generated based on the values of First report.
For getting column values i am using OnCellSelect event of JqGrid,

Event:

```
$('#Report1').jqGrid({
...
..
colNames: ['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6','name7'],
                        colModel: [
                        {....},
                        { ... },
                        { ...},
                        {...},
                        { ...},
                        { ...},
                        { ... }
                    ],
                        jsonReader: {
                            root: 'DD_data',
                            id: 'name1',
                            repeatitems: false
                        },
                        pager: $('#pager'),
//Event fires when clicked on name7
onCellSelect: function (rowid, index, contents, event) {   

//Code for generating Second Report based on First report data//
$('#Report2').jqGrid({
...
...
});
} 
});
```

Here in Cell Select event i am only getting rowid , my key , and selected cell content.

But i also need name2,name3 and name4 data from the selected column to generate second Report.

Is it possible in JqGrid.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `getCell` or `getRowData` to get the data from the row based on `rowid`. If you use `datatype: "local"` or if you use `loadonce: true` option in the grid `#Report1` then you can use `getLocalRow` which have some advantages over `getRowData`, but works only if the data are saved locally inside of internal `data` parameter. The parameter will be filled only if `datatype` is not `"json"` or `"xml"` or if it's `"json"` or `"xml"`, but `loadonce: true` option are used.

The simplest code which you can use would be

```js
onCellSelect: function (rowid) {
    var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
    // now you can use rowData.name2, rowData.name3, rowData.name4 ,...
}
```

Usage of `getLocalRow` could have some advantages (including performance advantage), but you should verify whether it works together with `datatype` and `loadonce` which you use in the grid `#Report1`.