# Jqgrid how to write cell click event

Tags: jqgrid

I want to write an event when user click on a cell of `jqgrid`. Is there build in method?
I could not find any event at [this link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks and jQuery events are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events). jqGrid register `click` handler on the body of the grid. Inside of the `click` handler the callbacks `beforeSelectRow` and later `onCellSelect` will be called. In the same way jQuery events `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` and `jqGridCellSelect` will be called too.

The callbacks and the events contains `e` parameter ([jQuery Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)) which [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property could be used to get all information about the click event if the other parameters of the `beforeSelectRow` callback (or `onCellSelect` callback) don't provides already what you need. The old answers: [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946955/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500239/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515553/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26861047/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and many other provide you examples of the usage of `onCellSelect` and `beforeSelectRow` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

there is a inbuilt event.. you can find it here [LINK](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)

```
onCellSelect: function (rowId, iCol, content, event) {
      //YOUR STUFF
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have double click event in jqgrid which can be used like this

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowId, iRow, iCol, e) { //Your Code  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
onSelectRow: function(){
                var row_id = $("#grid_nueva_caja_matriz").getGridParam('selrow');
                jQuery('#grid_nueva_caja_matriz').editRow(row_id, true);
            }
```

or you can use the differentes events how
ondblClickRow
you can check on the documentation of jqgrid