# CustomFormatter for JQgrid updates title attribute of td instead of adding html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I'm having some trouble creating a custom formatter for one of my cells. I'm trying to add in a progress bar for a specific cell, but it seems that the html code/ javascript code is being thrown in the title rather than the actual body of the td.

Here's the code for the custom formatter.

```
{ name: 'StudyCacheStatus', index: 'StudyCacheStatus', width: 15, align: 'center', formatter: CacheStatusFormatter}],

function CacheStatusFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    if (typeof cellValue === 'string') { return cellValue; }
    var cellValueHtml = cellValue.text;
    //obviously we are adding a button
    if (cellValue.buttonText) {
        var buttonHtml = ' <input type="button" value="' + cellValue.buttonText + '" onclick="' + cellValue.buttonCallBack + '"/>';
        cellValueHtml += buttonHtml;
    }
    else if (cellValue.progressBarValue)
    {
        var progressBarHtml = '<div id="progress-bar-' + cellValue.Uid + '>' + cellValue.progressBarValue +'</div>';
        + '<script> $( "#progress-bar-' + cellValue.Uid + '").progressbar({value:' + cellValue.progressBarValue + '});</script>';
        cellValueHtml += progressBarHtml;
    }
    return cellValueHtml;
}
```

The odd part is that the input button html is added properly to the cell, even though they're being populated the same way.

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title=" " aria-describedby="list_StudyCacheStatus"> 
     <input type="button" value="Cache on Server" onclick="CacheStudy('12345');">
</td>
```

However the progress bar html ends up like this.

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="<div id='progress-bar-12345>5" aria-describedby="list_StudyCacheStatus"></td>
```

I thought it might be due to trying to force a javascript function to run in the customformatter, so I commented out the script tag, but I had the same result. What exactly am i doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, but injection of `<script>` element inside of every `<td>` element of the column is absolutely wrong way. Could you describe what you want to implement? Which `progressbar` you use? Is it from jQuery UI or some other? Which advantage to have progressbar with one fixed `value` in the cell? Do you want to have it under the `<input>` button or on the side? What should do `onclick` function? Which `datatype` you use? Which format have input data? **Which version of jqGrid/[free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)/[Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) you use?**

Comment: Hi, I'm just trying to implement a progress bar to show the current cache update status. Progress bar is from jquery-ui 1.11. The progress bar is shown after the input button is pressed, and the button should go away afterwards. I just have it there since it was odd that it worked, but the div did not. Jqgrid version is version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of [the custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) is providing custom HTML fragment **as string**. The value returned from the custom formatter will be used as content of `<td>` element.

I would recommend you to reduce the code of your custom formatter to `return <input type="button" value="' + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellValue.buttonText) + '"/>';` or `return <button type="button">' + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellValue.buttonText) + '</button>';`. To implement `onclick` logic I would recommend you to use `beforeSelectRow` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647943/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637070/315935) for more details. If you want to show the progress bar in the cell *if the user click* the button in the cell then you can hide the button in the cell inside of `beforeSelectRow` callback, create and place the `<div>` *dynamically* inside of the clicked cell and to call `.progressbar(...)`. You can consider don't place the progress inside of the cell at all and to use `position:absolute` for the div and to place the progressbar *over the whole grid*. There are many implementation alternatives. You can decide yourself which one more corresponds your requirements. I want just stress that one should not place `<script>` inside of `<td>` and one don't need to use and `onclick` attribute too.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't understand why the current function updates the <td> title attribute instead of inserting it in the body. It's possible to do it differently, but I'd like to know why it's behaving like that.

Comment: @Bird: I can answer on your question only if you provides the demo with exact input data which generate the problem. You use old jqGrid 4.6. So you should not expect any bug fix. You can try to replace your URLs with jqGrid to the URLs of the latest free jqGrid (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)). I could debug the code and make the bug fix if I would be able to reproduce the problem. In general jqGrid construct `<td>` contain as the string. It can be that some quote produce the problem or `>` symbol

Comment: Looks like it was just some invalid quotations. Thanks for the assistance!